# Proof of the principle of well-ordered induction in the book of Rosen's Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, well-orders

I'm studying the proof given in Rosen's discrete mathematics for well-ordered induction.

**THE PRINCIPLE OF WELL-ORDERED INDUCTION**:
Suppose that S is a well-ordered set. The P(x) is true for all x $\in$ S, if

**INDUCTIVE STEP**: For every y $\in$ S, if P(x) is true for all x $\in$ S with x $\prec$ y, then P(y) is true.

**Proof**:
Suppose it is not the case that P(**x**) is true for all **x** $\in$ S. Then there is an element **y** $\in$ S such that P(**y**) is false. Consequently, the set A = {**x** $\in$ S | P(**x**) is false} is nonempty. Because S is well ordered, A has a least element **a**.

By the choice of **a** as a least element of A, we know that P(**x**) is true for all **x** $\in$ S with **x** $\prec$ **a**. <-- (I couldn't understand how it gets this)

This implies by the inductive step P(**a**) is true. This contradiction shows that P(**x**) must be true for all **x** $\in$ S.

---

My question is : where does the sentence, "By the choice of **a** as a least element of A, we know that P(**x**) is true for all **x** $\in$ S with **x** $\prec$ **a**.", come from?

I mean if we want to prove

"The P(x) is true for all x $\in$ S, if for every y $\in$ S, if P(x) is true for all x $\in$ S with x $\prec$ y",

Why can the conclusion "The P(x) is true for all x $\in$ S" be used in the proof? I remember it's not valid to do so while proving something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part 1: Justifying the assertion you are asking about.

Note that $\mathbf{a}$ is the smallest element of the set $A$. $A$ is the collection of all elements of $S$ for which $P(\mathbf{x})$ is not true.

Suppose $\mathbf{x}\in S$. If $P(\mathbf{x})$ is false, then $\mathbf{x}\in A$, so that means that $\mathbf{a}\preceq\mathbf{x}$ (because $\mathbf{a}$ is the **smallest** element of $A$).

So: $P(\mathbf{x})$ is false $\implies$ $\mathbf{a}\preceq \mathbf{x}$.

The contrapositive is that if $\mathbf{x}\prec \mathbf{a}$, then $P(\mathbf{x})$ is true.

So: for all $\mathbf{x}\in S$, if $\mathbf{x}\prec\mathbf{a}$, then $P(\mathbf{x})$ is true.

---

Part 2: Rest of your question:

We are not assuming what we are trying to prove: we are assuming the *opposite* of what we are trying to prove: that there is at least one element of $S$ for which $P(\mathbf{x})$ is false. From that assumption, we conclude that the set $A$ is not empty, and so has a smallest element. The next thing we *deduce* from this is *not* that “every element $\mathbf{x}$ of $S$ satisfies $P(\mathbf{x})$”. What we deduce is that “every element $\mathbf{x}$ of $S$ is **either** greater than $\mathbf{a}$, or else $P(\mathbf{x})$ holds.”

We never assume “$P(\mathbf{x})$ is true for all $\mathbf{x}\in S$”.

Comment: I understand where I got wrong. But I have a new question : what does happen if **a** is the smallest element in set S? I mean while **a** is the smallest element in S, we can't use inductive step to show P(a) is true and use contradiction to show the set containing **a** doesn't exist.

Comment: @tanchihpin0517 If $\mathbf{a}$ were the smallest element of $S$, then the condition “For all $\mathbf{x}\in S$ with $\mathbf{x}\prec\mathbf{a}$ we have $P\mathbf{x})$ is true” would be true by vacuity (the premise of the implication, $\mathbf{x}\prec\mathbf{a}$, is always false, so the implication is always true). But that would again imply that $P(\mathbf{a})$ must hold by our assumption that whenever the condition holds for all smaller elements, then it holds for $\mathbf{a}$.

Comment: I got it. It's really amazing. Thank you so much!